# Ember "needs" causes previous controller methods to fail

Tags: ember.js

Ember:  v1.0.0-rc.3-112-g3ec3711
EmberData: Last commit: f8cb714 (2013-04-28 07:24:47 -0700)

Im having a struggle with the "needs" api for cross controller communication.

I define a top level controller in my Application.Route like so

```
this.controllerFor('header').set('model', Nucleus.User.find(1));
```

So i have my header that doesnt belong to a specific url and needs to be there all the time.

And i have the related HeaderController with a few methods.

```
  userName: function () {
    return this.get('firstName') + " " + this.get('lastName');
  }.property('firstName', 'lastName'),

  clientLogo: function () {
    return Nucleus.localDomain + 'Content/images/logos/logo_' + this.get('currentClient') + '.png';
  }.property('currentClient'),

  clientClaimBillText: function () {
    if (this.get('clientType') === "PropertyAndCasualty") {
      return "Bill";
    }
    return "Claim";
  }.property('clientType')
```

In my URL as i travel down nested routes /clients/someClient/claims/1/1,

when i get to the ClaimController. I have a partial in the claim template that needs to access the "clientClaimBillText" method of the header controller.

in my ClaimController, i specify the "needs" api

```
Nucleus.ClaimController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['header']

});
```

and in my claim template i am calling this partial. Where i need access to the HeaderController property.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="_claim_header">
  <div id="page_header" class="silver_gradient">
        <div class="sub_nav_content">
            <div class="sub_nav_left">
                <label class="page_title">{{controllers.header.clientClaimBillText}} Action</label>
            </div>
            <div class="sub_nav_right">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

The partial renders properly. The problem im having is the template for the header seems to loose its state. Like it blows away the UserObject. All of the bound properties re render but without the user object that it was set to. Its like the original Nucleus.User.find(1) is gone.

Hopefully its something trivial im missing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything obvious. Sounds like you may have two instances of "header" controller. Are they the same object id?

```
// in Application.Route
controller = this.controllerFor('header');
controller.set('model', Nucleus.User.find(1));
console.log ('from app route header controller is: ', controller.toString());

// in your template
<pre>Header controller is; {{controllers.header}}</pre>
```